# Git file diff/history with renames

Tags: git

I need to do a git diff between the the file at the current HEAD and a past date.  However here's the kicker: the file extension has been RENAMED which poses a problem for most GUI tools.  ie, XCode has this feature but it breaks because of the renamed file despite git being (I think) capable of doing this.

Does anyone know how to manually perform this diff?

thanks

Comment: Single file or multiple files?

Comment: single files____________

Answer (score 2):

For any single file, you can just use `revision:path` syntax on both files. For example, you can do the following.

```
git diff HEAD:Foo 1af1f21845f:Foo.cc
```